# home-server tag makes no sense

Tags: discussion, tags

From looking at [home-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/home-server) there's nothing there that can't just go in [server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/server)

Answer (score 6):

### Merge it with [server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/server).

The only "difference" is that a home server will do a lot more stuff than say, a companies server. (as in, it'll run many different services as opposed to say, one or two.)

Answer (score -4):

## No, keep it!

We need our home server tag!

*edit away with reasons to keep it folks*